# Replace or create a new view within a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I built an activity which takes data from a rss file and shows them on a ListFragment; this is how I defined it on the layout file:

```
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/news_list_fragment"
        android:name="com.thecoffeedrinker.theforcereader.NewsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout" />
```

It might happen that there is no connection available; this case I want the application to show a layout to warn the user about it, to be shown in the same layout area of the list. What's the best thing to do to achieve this? Should I create a "disconnected fragment" class and replace an instance with the list on the same activity? Should I load this layout within the List Fragment class? I tried to replace it but when I resume the activity it crashes...why is that? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Before I can answer you question, I need some more info: Can you tell us what code you implemented further more? Did you implement onResume? How did you try to replace it? Have you considered  inflating a different lay-out? Or have you considered to have both fragments there, 1 with width/height0dp and one active being visible?

Answer (score 0):

**To Replace one Fragment with Another**

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

**Adding new Fragment**

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: ...I know about this, and it didn't answer my question.